# Orthogonal complement of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I don't understand how to visualize these statements algebraically (are they true or false??):

Let $S$ and $T$ be subspaces of $E$:

I) $(S+T)^\perp \subset S^\perp \cap T^\perp$

II) $S^\perp + T^\perp \subset(S+T)^\perp$

Comment: You can use an orthogonal base

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in (S+T)^\perp$ then for all $y\in S\subset S+T$ we have $\langle x,y\rangle=0$ so $x\in S^\perp$ and similarly we prove that $x\in T^\perp$ hence we get I).

We can see that II) is false using the counterexample : $S=span(1,0)$ and $T=span(0,1)$.